# Lua - check if array exists

Tags: arrays, string, lua

I'm trying to find out if a certain array exists via an if statement such as

```
if array{} == nil then array = {} else print("it exists") end
```

The above doesn't work it seems and I have no way of checking if it exists, basically I'm creating an AddOn which scans a log for a certain event and if it's true it returns the spellName. I wish to create an array with that spellName, however spellName = {} doesn't work as it seems to just create a new array (rather than updating the existing one).

```
local _SPD = CreateFrame("Frame");
_SPD:RegisterEvent("COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED");
_SPD:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event, ...)

local timestamp, type, sourceName = select(1, ...), select(2, ...), select(5, ...)

if (event == "COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED") then
    if select(2,...) == "SPELL_AURA_APPLIED" then
        if select(5,...) == UnitName("player") then

            local spellID, spellName = select(12, ...), select(13, ...)

             spellName = { 
                sourceName = {

                } 
            }

            table.insert(spellName["sourceName"], {id = spellID, stamp = timestamp })

            for k,v in pairs ( spellName["sourceName"] ) do
                print (k.. ": " ..v["id"].. " at " ..v["stamp"])
            end 
        end
    end
end
end);
```

Basically it's just re-creating the table every time a certain aura is applied on me (which is expected behavior)

I've banged my head but I have no idea how to check if spellName (and sourceName) exists and if so do not create them again since in this case the variable already exists because it returns the value to me so I can't check if they're nil as they won't be, I need to somehow check if a table exists on those values and if not create them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `local spellID, spellName = select(12, ...), select(13, ...)` is silly. Get rid of the `, select(13, ...)` and just leave the `select(12, ...)`. `select()` actually returns all values, starting with the given index, not just a single value, so saying `local a, b = select(12, ...)` will assign the 12th arg to `a` and the 13th arg to `b`.

Comment: @KevinBallard, that should save me some space, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration for **table** checking is wrong. Use it like this:

```lua
if type(array) == "table" then
  print("it exists")
else
  array = {}
end
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this could be written as `array = type(array) == "table" and array or {}`.

Comment: You could have just written `if type(array) == 'table' then` -- which will return `nil` if array is nil, making the first test unnecessary.

Comment: @Mud hmm, I didn't know that `type` can take nil arguments. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've added the following lines: 
                                  
    `print(spellName)
    if type(array) == spellName then
    print("it exists")
    else
    spellName = {}
    print(spellName)
    print("created")
    end` 
and it seems to return the first print with the spellName but the one after the creation of the table returns with a table number (which is different everytime I run the spell while the first print stays the same.

Comment: You need to use `if type(spellName) == "table"` as your if condition.

Comment: I've changed it to: 
`if type(spellName) == "table" then
     print("it exists")
     else
     print(spellName)
     print(type(spellName))
     spellName = {}
     print(type(spellName))
     print(spellName)
     print("created")
    end`
 I get the following information back after I cast a spell called Riptide: `Riptide, string, table, table: 0000000000044570830 created`, another run of this is identical with the exception of the table number which changes slightly at the end. I think it's because the variable exists as string, table and string when it's run. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @user2026598 The number is the memory address of table. It is perfectly normal for it to change.

Comment: Aha! It keeps prompting created on the same spell whereas it should say 'exists' on subsequent runs. I'm completely lost as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
local spellID, spellName = select(12, ...), select(13, ...)
spellName = spellName or {}
spellName.sourceName = spellName.sourceName or {}
table.insert(spellName.sourceName, {id = spellID, stamp = timestamp })
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, returned an error `Locals: (*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = <table> {
 id = 52127
 stamp = 1359598562.074
}
(*temporary) = "table expected, got nil"`

Comment: @user2026598 - Edited my answer. Try again please.

Comment: didn't seem to work either, however adding `myTable = {}` at the top and using `if myTable[spellName] then print("exists") else myTable[spellName] = {} end` seemed to do the trick. Thanks to the following people in this thread: http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1257678-LUA-Arrays-detection-%28on-a-variable-returned-as-string%29